# How to load saved KMeans model (in ML Pipeline)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I'm learning scala and am trying without success to load a model that I have run/fit on data. It took 6 hours to run and I'm afraid I'm going to have to rerun this if I can't figure out a way to save/load the output.

I ran the KMeans as part of a pipeline. I saved the output of the pipeline that I ran on my training dataset as 'model' and that was what I tried to load.

After running the model I was able to save(or at least I thought I was) it using:

```
model.write.overwrite().save("/analytics_shared/qoe/km_model")
```

My question is how do I load it back so I can then use it to cluster/score new data without having to rerun the training that takes 6 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [KMeansModel.load](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel$@load(path:String):org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel) method.

> **load(path: String): KMeansModel** Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read.load(path)`.

In your case, it'd be as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeansModel
val model = KMeansModel.load("/analytics_shared/qoe/km_model")
```

> I ran the KMeans as part of a pipeline. I saved the output of the pipeline that I ran on my training dataset as 'model' and that was what I tried to load.

With ML Pipeline it's even easier as you simply replace `KMeansModel` with [PipelineModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$).

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
val model = PipelineModel.load("/analytics_shared/qoe/km_model")
```

Comment: That worked! I kept loading ml.Pipeline not ml.PipelineModel so it kept coming back as an error. You rock! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great answer! They should add your reply to their documentation! I wasted a lot of time searching this on Spark documentation...